# How to initialize a DB connection in Module.scala in the play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to scala. I want to initialize a DB connection when the application starts. So this should be done in the `Module.scala` file. I tried the following line, but it throws an error:

```
val conn = DB.connect()
```

Comment: Please consider adding the error message in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a Singleton and do an eager initialize:

Singleton (DB Init):

```
@Singleton
class PetDBInitializer @Inject()() {
  // your init code
  val conn = DB.connect()
}
```

The `Module.scala` looks like:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {

  override def configure(): Unit = {

    bind(classOf[PetDBInitializer])
      .asEagerSingleton()

    // more config
  }
}
```